# Remote access softwares for android mobiles

Tags: android, remote-access

Is there software for unattended remote screen sharing on android? On laptops, there is software like jumpdesktop and teamviewer that can be installed on local and remote system for unattended access. But I am looking for remote access between two android devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Getscreen](https://getscreen.me/) remote access - simply install an agent on one of the phones and send a link to connect and you will gain access to the other device as soon as the user clicks on the link. It is also possible to connect from the phone to a computer. Hope this advice will be useful.

I'm person, affiliated with Getscreen.